# Linear Algebra - Finding eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can someone help me find the eigenvalues for this matrix? I can't seem to find it lol...

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 3 \\
        0 & 1 & 4 \\
        3 & 4 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Maybe this is a specific type of matrix?

One try following the above by solving for $$\det(A - \lambda I)=0$$

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 - \lambda & 0 & 3 \\
        0 & 1 - \lambda & 4 \\
        3 & 4 & 1 - \lambda \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
Add Column 1 to Column 3

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 - \lambda & 0 & 4 - \lambda \\
        0 & 1 - \lambda & 4 \\
        3 & 4 & 4 - \lambda \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

And then let's say I end up with this so far:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 - \lambda & 0 & 4 - \lambda \\
        0 & 1 - \lambda & 4 \\
        2 + \lambda & 4 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I just seem to go around in circles which is why I failed an exam last time...

Comment: Solving for $$det(A - \lambda I )$$, pretty much how they do it in my book on the current subchapter.

Comment: include what you have so far in your post and we can see where you get stuck and get you get unstuck

Comment: What did you get for the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Gave one example of what I do...

Comment: @Myzanthros Do you know about Laplace expansion? By the way, at position $(3,3)$ you should have $1-\lambda$, not $4-\lambda$; and $3$, not $4-\lambda$ at position $(1,3)$.

Comment: How did you end up with $4-\lambda$ in the upper right and lower right positions? These should be $3$ and $1 - \lambda$, respectively.

Comment: I added column 1 to column 3, if you see my original matrix, I'll edit that too since it seems to be confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used $x$ instead of $\lambda$. You should have
$$A-xI=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 3 \\
        0 & 1 & 4 \\
        3 & 4 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}x & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & x & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & x\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
1-x & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 1-x & 4 \\
3 & 4 & 1-x \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Expanding the determinant by the first row:
$$\begin{aligned}\det(A-xI)&=(1-x)\begin{vmatrix}1-x & 4 \\ 4 & 1-x \end{vmatrix}+3\begin{vmatrix} 0 & 1-x\\ 3 & 4 \end{vmatrix}\\
&=(1-x)\left((1-x)^2-16\right)+9(x-1)\\
&=(1-x)^3-25(1-x)\\
&=(1-x)((1-x)^2-25)\\
&=(1-x)(1-x+5)(1-x-5)\\
&=(1-x)(6-x)(-4-x)\\
&=(x+4)(x-1)(6-x)\\
\end{aligned}$$
The roots of $\det(A-xI)=0$ are $x=-4,1,6$. These are the eigenvalues.

Comment: Ahhhh, of course, I forgot you have to expand along column 3 as well *facepalm*, thank you this was all I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can write : 
$x_1 +3x_3 = \lambda x_1$
$x_2 + 4x_3 = \lambda x_2$
$3x_1 +4x_2 +x_3 = \lambda x_3$

And you solve, you have 
$3x_3 = (\lambda-1) x_1$ 
$4x_3 = (\lambda-1) x_2$
$3x_1 +4x_2 +x_3 = \lambda x_3$

so $\lambda = 1$ works
and else you have ${(\lambda -1)}^2 = 25$ so $\lambda = 6$ or $\lambda = -4$

You just have to find the corresponding $x_1$, $x_2$ $x_3$  and check that's not $0,0,0$.

Comment: Thanks yeah I get it now, I totally forgot about the "3" hehe...;P